# Does github auto add files created in sublime?

Tags: git, github, sublimetext3

I'm new to github and having difficulty adding content to a repository.

I manually tried to add and commit files from cmd, git cmd, and git bash cmd, using the command line and the repository weas not changed.
I tried closing my projects in sublime and re-opening them and this did not work either.

```
C:\Users\Mack\Desktop\Election Model>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The repository is here: https://github.com/Mack1/Election-Model

I'd like to delete the React files and add an additional file in my next commit. I was rate limited running a script using selenium, but, my plan is to try it again using a strategy suggested by a friend. Exponential steps with the timer. I also think modifying the header is probably a wise idea while using such scripts.

Comment: Did you push? Just committing means you modify your local repository. The repository on github.com will only ever change when you push to it.

Comment: I think you have a few questions here! `git` just tracks the contents you add to a repository or is already tracked by one. One normally also deals with local copies of the repository and pushes or pulls changes to and from the remote repository. GitHub is a service which provides remote repositories and tooling for working with `git`, but is distinct from the tool!

Comment: I don't think I've used push. If I used push I forgot about it. I tried pushing C:\Users\Mack\Desktop\Election-Model>git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify Joachim Sauer's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127059/does-github-auto-add-files-created-in-sublime#comment113398520_64127059), you need to run `git push` to push your local changes back to the git server, which in this case is Github. The full command would likely be

```
git push origin master
```

if you haven't made any branches. As you make more changes, you still need to `git add` new files and `git commit` changes made, *then* do a `git push` to update the server.